# How to set the umask of Docker service with systemd

Tags: systemd, docker

I'd like to start my Docker service with *systemd* with a umask of 0002 (instead of the default 0022). So I created an override file under `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` with

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

And reloaded the daemon with `systemctl daemon-reload` and also restarted the Docker service.
But when I look at `/proc/<PID>/status` I still see 0022 as umask, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this even possible? See https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/13941/files - is the daemon forcing the umask and it doesn't matter how you actually start it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down.

`Umask=` is documented in `man systemd.exec`. You can find which man page it's documented in by checking `man systemd.directives`. It's documented as:

> "Controls the file mode creation mask. "

The output you see in `/proc/<pid>/status` is documented in `man proc`. It's documented as:

> "Process umask".

So first, it's not clear that what your checking is the right test of the `systemd` directive you set. A better test would be to look at a file created by Docker. What `umask` was created as?

Second, check that your `systemd` directive actually took hold. Review the output of:

```
 systemd-analyze dump
```

Search in the output for `Docker`, and from there you can find the `Umask` that `systemd` has set for the `Docker` service. Does `systemd` see your `umask` as you expect?

Your `systemd` syntax appears correct, so I think this may be a misunderstanding about what the `Umask=` directive does.

Comment: I find this a rather confusing answer.   If I set a umask for a process - which is what I presume the directive is doing, I'd expect that to be what is visible in /proc/<PID>/status - no?  Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: I don't suppose the capital M in uMask is the problem?  I know the docs write it that way, but umask is not usually written in camel case.  Just a thought.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be (and of course I meant UMask- but you get the idea).